# Taking the first character of each string in an array to create a new string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to take the first character of each item in an array and join those to create a new string. Then i want to do the same with the second characters, third characters, and finally 4th characters.

For example I have the following array:

```
let arr = ["abcd", "efgh, "ijkl", "mnop"]
```

would then turn into the string...

```
"aeim"
"bfjn"
"cgko"
"dhlp"
```

Comment: Before posting a question about a specific programming task you're trying to accomplish, it's expected that you make an attempt to solve the issue on your own first. Then if you're still stuck, include in your question details about what you've already tried and why/how it doesn't work. It's also helpful to include any code you've written, even if it doesn't work, since that will help us point you towards a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each element in the array has the same length, you could iterate over all indexes and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to construct a string from all the characters at that index.

(If you want to get the length of the shortest string when they have different lengths, you can use `Math.min(...arr.map(s => s.length))`.)

```js
let arr = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"];
const res = Array.from({length: arr[0].length}, (_, i) => 
              arr.map(s => s[i]).join(''));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The output is a string, not an array. You can modify your code and use `\n` to join elements in your array

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a combination of the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back to string:

```js
let arr = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"];
let result = Array.from({ length: arr[0].length }, (_, i) =>
  arr.map((item) => item[i]).join("")
);
console.log(result.join("\n"));
```

**Output:**

```
aeim
bfjn
cgko
dhlp
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to iterate over each position in the strings with simply two `for`-loops:

```js
let arr = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"];
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
  let currentString = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    currentString += arr[j].charAt(i);
  }
  result.push(currentString);
}

console.log(result.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is faster than simple string concatenation:

```js
let arr = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "1111"];
const res = Array(arr[0].length).fill('');
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < res.length; j++){
    res[j] += arr[i][j];
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

```
` Chrome/119
---------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     1.00x  |  x1000000  127  129  130  143  148
Unmitigated   3.93x  |  x1000000  499  505  510  514  523
---------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const arr = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "1111"];

// @benchmark Unmitigated
  Array.from({length: arr[0].length}, (_, i) => 
              arr.map(s => s[i]).join(''));

// @benchmark Alexander

const res = Array(arr[0].length).fill('');
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < res.length; j++){
    res[j] += arr[i][j];
  }
}
res;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```